# Where's the optimal place to strike a tuning fork, and how should it be oriented in relation to the ear, in order to achieve maximum amplitude?

Tags: acoustics

I recently bought a small tuning fork online, and when it arrived it turned out to be way smaller than I expected. It's barely audible, so you have to get it really close to your ear. It works and I don't regret the purchase, but it got me thinking:

If I wanted to maximize the perceived loudness from the tuning fork, how would I go about it? In the first place, where is the optimal place to excite, or hit, the tuning fork, for it to achieve the largest possible amplitude with any given force? In second place, once the tuning fork is vibrating, how should I orient it in relation to my ear for maximum perceived loudness?

Comment: Read the second paragraph, or more, it may help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuning_fork#Description

Answer (score 1):

Hold it against a surface (sounding board). Or put it on a quarter-wave resonator box. Or hold it against your teeth or on your skull behind the ear.